# I'm using datejs in an ascx, but it's causing problems for my ajax calendar extender

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datejs

I'm using the below code to call the correct culture datejs file:

```
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Date/date-" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name + ".js") %>"></script>
```

I then use the datejs to do some culture specific formatting in a function:

```
dateTextbox.value = today.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDate);
```

The reason for this function is because I have a textbox/calendar-extender for selecting a date, and a textbox for entering a number of days. A change to one causes the other to update client side to keep them in sync.

My problem is that when I am using datejs, it overrides the original Date type which is needed in calendar-extender, so if I now click my textbox to select a date, then it throws because of type discrepancy.

Is there a way to make it only use the datejs in my functions, rather than having it throughout the whole control/page, or can I turn it off (so to speak) after it's been used, or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up...decided not to use datejs, but instead am now using my own function in a new script which I'll build upon as different languages are required.

Here is the function I'm now using:

```
//convert a date into a string in a culture specific format
function FormatDate(thisDate, culture) {

    var date = thisDate.getDate();
    var month = thisDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = thisDate.getFullYear();

    var strDate = date.toString();
    if (strDate.length == 1)
        strDate = ("0" + strDate);

    var strMonth = month.toString();
    if (strMonth.length == 1)
        strMonth = ("0" + strMonth);

    culture = culture.toLowerCase();

    switch (culture) {
        case "en-gb":
            return (strDate + "/" + strMonth + "/" + year.toString());
            break;

        case "en-us":
            return (strMonth + "/" + strDate + "/" + year.toString());
            break;

        default:
            return (strDate + "/" + strMonth + "/" + year.toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

and here is how I call it:

```
var today = new Date();
today = today.getDateOnly();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + commentPeriod);

dateTextbox.value = 
    FormatDate(today, "<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name %>");
```